# increase the length of lines created by pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a command to draw some lines through a text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \begin{document}

\scalebox{0}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        \addplot [
        color=orange,
        solid,
        line width=1.3pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{oranged}
        \addplot [
        color=red!30.6!green!0!blue!55.7!,
        densely dashed,
        line width=1.7pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{purpled}
        \addplot [
        color=green,
        dash pattern={on 10pt off 2pt},
        line width=1.6pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{greened}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


 I have \ref{purpled} and \ref{oranged}  and \ref{greened}.


 \end{document}
```

This command creates lines with a special length. I did anything to increase the **length** of the lines, although I was not succesful. does anyone know how we reach this goal.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what are you trying to do; pgfplots if for drawing graphics. Are you sure you don't want some of the text underlining/highlighting packages? Can you add a (even handmade) sketch with the result you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are attempting to do, but it is better to just use `tikz` directly to draw instead of using `pgfplots`.

In the code below, the `\DrawLine` macro will draw a line of a given length with given draw parameters. I used `\DrawLine` to define `\Purpled`, `\Greened` and `\Oranged` which yields the second line below:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\DrawLine}[2][]{%
    \tikz [baseline] \draw [#1] (0,0.5ex) -- ++(#2,0);%
}
\newcommand*{\Purpled}[1]{%
    \DrawLine[
        draw=red!30.6!green!0!blue!55.7!, 
        dash pattern={on 10pt off 2pt}, 
        densely dashed,
        line width=1.6pt,
    ]{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\Greened}[1]{%
    \DrawLine[
        draw=green,
        dash pattern={on 10pt off 2pt},
        line width=1.6pt,
    ]{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\Oranged}[1]{%
    \DrawLine[
        draw=orange,
        solid,
        line width=1.3pt,
    ]{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\scalebox{0}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        \addplot [
        color=orange,
        solid,
        line width=1.3pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{oranged}
        \addplot [
        color=red!30.6!green!0!blue!55.7!,
        densely dashed,
        line width=1.7pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{purpled}
        \addplot [
        color=green,
        dash pattern={on 10pt off 2pt},
        line width=1.6pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{greened}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


 I have \ref{purpled} and \ref{oranged}  and \ref{greened}.

 I have \Purpled{0.65cm} and \Oranged{1.0cm}  and \Greened{1.0cm}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to be so generous and intelligent!!!